# D3 descending scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

Given a set of number 0 to 1, I need a d3 scaling function that returns 0 to 100.

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear();
scale.domain([0,1]);
scale.range([0,100]);
scale(0.1);  // 10
```

This works great.  However, because I'm setting opacity for data elements based on confidence intervals, I want the output (range) to diminish as the input (domain) increases.

So for example:

```
scale(0.1);  // should produce 90
scale(0.2);  // should produce 80
scale(0.3);  // should produce 70
```

So as the scale input goes up, the output goes down.

How can I instruct the scale object to do this?

Comment: Set a different range?

Comment: The point is by default the linear range produces values that scale positively with inputs.  Put in 0.1 and it gives you 10, put in 0.2 and it gives you 20.  I want to put in 0.1 to get 90, 0.2 to get 80, etc.

Comment: Yes, so `.range([100,0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to provide a range that behaves accordingly:

```
scale.range([100,0]);
```

Note that you could also reverse the domain in this case with the same effect.